# Scalaz Kleisli question

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.8, scalaz

There is a `trait` called **Kleisli** in the [scalaz](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) library. Looking at the code:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
type StringPair = (String, String)

val f: Int => List[String]        = (i: Int) => List((i |+| 1).toString, (i |+| 2).toString)
val g: String => List[StringPair] = (s: String) => List("X" -> s, s -> "Y")

val k = kleisli(f) >=> kleisli(g) //this gives me a function: Int => List[(String, String)]
```

Calling the function `k` with the value of 2 gives:

```
println( k(2) ) //Prints: List((X,3), (3,Y), (X,4), (4,Y))
```

My question is: *how would I use Scalaz to combine f and g to get a function m such that the output of m(2) would be:*

```
val m = //??? some combination of f and g
println( m(2) ) //Prints: List((X,3), (X,4), (3,Y), (4,Y))
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want [`transpose`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/Data-List.html#transpose). Scalaz doesn't supply this, but it should be easy to write. The function `m` that you want is `val m = f andThen (_.map(g)) andThen transpose andThen (_.join)`

Comment: I'm not able to try this right now, but can't we use MA#sequence to perform transposition? http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleTraverse.scala.html

Comment: You're right. You totally can, given the "zippy" Applicative instance for streams (or ZipStream).